# Is there a way to create a symbolic link with an argument? (linux)

Tags: python, linux, bash, shared-libraries, symlink

I'd like to replace python (symbolic link) with a shortcut that calls it as an ld.so argument:
e.g.

```
/home/user/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7
```

instead of (the default)

```
/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7
```

Notes:

1. I need it as a link and not as an alias because my IDE debugger (pycharm) explicitly calls the link.
2. It should be able to support additional command line arguments if exist

Just using `ln -s` won't work, because it doesn't accepts arguments. **I tried to wrap it as a bash script instead**, but it doesn't works as well (works ok from command line, but SegFault when being called from the IDE debugger)

Is there another way for doing that?

EDIT (for clarification):
Here is what I tried for the bash script (works ok from the  command line, but yield segmentation fault when being called from the IDE debugger)

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64:$HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$HOME/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/:$HOME/my_libc_env/usr/lib/"  $HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so $HOME/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 "${@}"
```

Comment: first of all, do you know what a symbolic link is?

Comment: Try using `exec`… i.e., `LD_LIB... exec $HOME/...` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, Thanks, it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You can specify where to find a particular shared library by setting the value of the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The value is a colon-separated list of directory names; in this case, you want to prepend a specific directory so that it will be checked first.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7
```

A wrapper script makes this simpler, forgoing the need to remember either the library path or the path to your Python executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wrote in the question that I already tried this approach and it didn't work. (I'll clarify about also trying with LD_LIBRARY_PATH)